# What are some strategies for researching an under-documented recording?

Tags: recording

If some music is accessible online in a page giving only the title of the track and the name of the main performer, how can you try to find the date, location, and other performers?

More generally, the recording could be offline too, following a comment on the original version of this question ( "I was intrigued by a Youtube video," "I found a pirated recording on a Maxwell cassette tape in a drawer," or "Somebody made passing mention in a biography of a memorable studio session.")

Comment: If it was me, I'd try the recording rights registries. 


https://www.ascap.com/repertory#/

https://www.sesac.com/repertory/search

https://www.songfile.com/public-search

Comment: Different people will contribute different answers or comments, depending on what "works for them", but the combination of all of that will be a useful answer.